# WEKA + Java: get class probabilities

Tags: java, weka, libsvm

Given the following binary classifier:

```
LibSVM classifier = new LibSVM();
classifier.setCost(cost);
classifier.setGamma(gamma);
```

performing the following operation returns the label for the instance:

```
double classId = classifier.classifyInstance(instance);
```

However, I would like to obtain the degree of confidence for this classification (i.e., probability that the instance is in the positive class + probability that the instance is in the negative class).

How can I obtain this information? Is it possible to have it?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that there are not enough information to answer this. Moreover, it does not look like to be a Java problem. It seems to be  a problem about mathematics.

Comment: Which is the missing information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using [SetProbabilityEstimates()](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/functions/LibSVM.html#setProbabilityEstimates(boolean)), which sets a flag for generating probability estimates?

There is also another option, -B, in [SetOptions()](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/functions/LibSVM.html#setOptions%28java.lang.String[]%29) that may help you generate these probability estimates.

Comment: Would be great to see this in context of the code above